# How to set executable permissions in jenkins

Tags: java, android, jenkins

I am trying to built my android app through Jenkins. It always fails the build with following error. Anyone know how can I Set executable permissions for gradle- 2.14.4. It works fine when I use gradle 2.2.

> Downloading
>   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
>
> Unzipping
>   /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
>   to
>   /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7
>
> Set executable permissions for:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7/gradle-2.14.1/bin/gradle
>   OS: Jenkins

Comment: I don't see an error in your post.

Comment: Error is:                                                                                                             Set executable permissions for: /var/lib/jenkins/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/4cj8p00t3e5ni9e8iofg8ghvk7/gradle-2.14.1/bin/gradle OS: Jenkins

Comment: Have you solve this yet?

Comment: @Emmanuel. I think I did.

Comment: @user1154390 Would you care to comment on how you solved the issue?